# Verify multiple REST requests by using MockRestServiceServer

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking

Supposedly I have the following endpoint: `https://dummy-url/api/query/elements?MY_CONDITION_1%20LESSOREQUAL%20{a_number}`

As you can see, `a_number` is a variable, where the value of it should be changed, for example in the following loop

```
public class Caller {

    public void callSomeThing() {
        int a_number = 0
        String URL = "https://dummy-url/api/query/elements?MY_CONDITION_1%20LESSOREQUAL%20";
        String updatedURL;
        while (a_number < 6) {
            updatedURL = URL + a_number;
            restTemplate.getForEntity(URI.create(updatedURL), String.class);
            a_number++;
        }
    }
}}
```

With the above logic, we have 6 REST calls to the endpoints

```
https://dummy-url/api/query/elements?MY_CONDITION_1%20LESSOREQUAL%200
https://dummy-url/api/query/elements?MY_CONDITION_1%20LESSOREQUAL%201
https://dummy-url/api/query/elements?MY_CONDITION_1%20LESSOREQUAL%202
https://dummy-url/api/query/elements?MY_CONDITION_1%20LESSOREQUAL%203
https://dummy-url/api/query/elements?MY_CONDITION_1%20LESSOREQUAL%204
https://dummy-url/api/query/elements?MY_CONDITION_1%20LESSOREQUAL%205
```

For testing, I adopted `MockRestServiceServer`. The idea of testing is straightforward: verify the REST calls should be requested 6 times. To implement this idea, I imagine something like the following.

```
@RestClientTest(Caller.class)
public class CallerTest {
    private static final String URL = "https://dummy-url/api/query/elements?MY_CONDITION_1%20LESSOREQUAL%20";

    @Autowired
    private Caller caller;

    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockRestServiceServer.reset();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldCall6Times() {
        int a_number_0 = 0;
        int a_number_1 = 1;
        int a_number_2 = 2;
        int a_number_3 = 3;
        int a_number_4 = 4;
        int a_number_5 = 5;

        mockRestServiceServer
                .expect(requestTo(URI.create(getUrl(a_number_0))))
                .andRespond(withSuccess());
                .expect(requestTo(URI.create(getUrl(a_number_1))))
                .andRespond(withSuccess());
                .expect(requestTo(URI.create(getUrl(a_number_2))))
                .andRespond(withSuccess());
                .expect(requestTo(URI.create(getUrl(a_number_3))))
                .andRespond(withSuccess());
                .expect(requestTo(URI.create(getUrl(a_number_4))))
                .andRespond(withSuccess());
                .expect(requestTo(URI.create(getUrl(a_number_5))))
                .andRespond(withSuccess());

        caller.callSomeThing();
    }

    private String getUrl(int a_number) {        
        return URL + a_number
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this implementation seems not to work. Could you guy help me?

Answer (score 0):

A possible way

```
@RestClientTest(Caller.class)
public class CallerTest {
    private static final String URL = "https://dummy-url/api/query/elements?MY_CONDITION_1%20LESSOREQUAL%20";

    @Autowired
    private Caller caller;

    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockRestServiceServer.reset();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldCall6Times() {
        IntStream.range(0, 6).forEach(i -> {
            mockRestServiceServer
                    .expect(requestTo(URI.create(getUrl(i))))
                    .andRespond(withSuccess());
        });


        caller.callSomeThing();
    }

    private String getUrl(int a_number) {        
        return URL + a_number
    }
}
```